# Creating list of divs by class

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-lists

I'm not sure whether I should be doing this with jquery or php, but I have a html page with several divs of the same class, but different ids. ie:

```
<div class="something" id="furniture">contents</div>
<div class="something" id="lighting">contents</div>
<div class="something" id="homewares">contents</div>
```

What I'm looking at doing is creating a `<ul>` generated by the ids of any div with the class "something".

Would I be best doing this using jquery? and how would I best go about creating a list/menu of these divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, to "convert" that structure into `ul`'s, code should look like:

```
 var $target = $('.something'),
     $parent = $target.parent(),
     $list   = $('<ul/>', {
       id:     'your_id_here',
       css:    {
           backgroundColor:  'red'
           // more css attributes, or use class: to assign a css class
     }
 });

 $target.each(function(){
     $list.append('<li>' + $(this)[0].id + '</li>');
 });   

 $target.remove();
 $parent.append($list);
```

That would replace the divs with `ul`'s. Importan thing in this example is to remove
the original `div` because of the ids, which have to be unique in a valid `html markup`.

Comment: Ah, this is closer to what I need, but II didn't express myself well.  There will be only one ul, but each id would convert to an li.

Answer (score 1):

You would use PHP if that is an option (i.e. you know the ids when you load the page and are generating them from your PHP already), otherwise only the people with JavaScript enabled are going to see your page content (and search engines would probably punish this "hidden" content).

If you have the list of ids in a PHP array you would do something like this:

```
<?php 
    $ids = array('furniture, 'lighting', 'homewares');
?>
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($ids as $id) : ?>
  <li><?=$id?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

If you wanted to use jQuery you could do this:

```
$('body').append('<ul id="yourID"></ul>');

$('div.something').each(function() {
    $('ul#yourID').append('<li>' + $(this).id + '</li>');
});
```

Update (you want to replace the `div` tags and put the ids on the `li` tags)

```
$('body').append('<ul id="yourID"></ul>');

$('div.something').each(function() {
    var $id = $(this).id;
    $(this).remove();
    $('ul#yourID').append('<li id="' + $id  + '">' + $id  + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Graphain for a quick response! 

Unfortunately, I need the list generated from the div ids as I'm coding for a friend who is only slightly familar with html. So he will simply be dropping in a div with the class "something" and will give it an id. 

This new div id will then be automatically listed in the `ul`. 

I want to make it as simple as possible for him, which means no arrays.

Comment: And how many people disable JS in their browsers? Cmon, if people do that then they should accept that half the internet will render incorrectly. The only people that have excuses are Bots

Comment: Then you probably have to use the JS example unless you want to have the PHP file read itself and parse out the `<div>` tags within itself.

Comment: @Lord Increasing numbers of people disable JS for security, privacy and convenience reasons. Plenty of sites have security loopholes, JS errors, loud/noisy/annoying ads and tracking scripts.  See the very popular plugin NoScript

Comment: @Lord Besides which Google will punish you pretty heavily (perhaps not for a small nav UL like this) if your JavaScript degraded page isn't close to your JavaScript enabled page.

Comment: Using JavaScript to solve this problem is a very bad idea. This is a server-side problem that needs a server-side solution, so PHP is the way to go. If you need simpler configuration than a PHP array, you can just use a separate configuration file that contains the values comma separated or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML you've provided is rendered, and that you have an available UL element on the page, you can use JQuery to do (something like) the following

```
jQuery('.something').each( 
function(index, Element) { 
    var newListElement = jQuery(document.createElement('li'));
    newListElement.html(Element.html());
    jQuery('#myul').append(newListElement);  
});
```

It's a bit unclear as to the restrictions that are imposed upon you, but I hope this helps.